# Solder alloys resistances for high current PCB laptop connections

Tags: soldering

Some time ago I had a problem with my laptop DC connector which force me to replace the PCB connector by a new one. After doing it, I have noticed that the connection becomes very hot and even the surrounding plastic has been damaged. Thinking that maybe the connector was a low quality connector (because I had to buy it to a china store which was the only way to find it), I have replaced the connector with a LiPo battery connector rated for higher currents. This connector was soldered to the PCB using a 2.5 mm cable which is rated for even higher currents, but the problem still there.
As the problem seems to start at the laptop PCB because the connector temperature is much lower, I have thought that maybe the problem is the solder used to connect the cable (I have supposed that the PCB width and thickness is correct).

My question is if the solder alloy can help to solve my problem and which is the best. Also I want to know if someone knows the nominal resistance of silver solder alloys, because I have bought solder and I am not fully sure if the alloy is which they tell.

For now I have the following tin references:

- 1mm Standard solder 60/40 (tin/lead) -> 0.24 ohm⋅m
- 2mm Plumber solder 95/5 (tin/silver) -> 0.02 ohm⋅m
- 1mm RoHS solder 96.5/3/0.5 (tin/silver/copper) -> 0.16 ohm⋅m

The latter is what I have bought and I am not sure about the real alloy, because is much near to the tin/lead alloy in resistance than to the plumber alloy (which is similar), but also the plumber solder is ticker and doesn't have a flux core.

My laptop current is about 12 A at 20 V.

Comment: Never use plumbing solder with electronics. And if you care about resistivity, you want resistivity metrics, Ω·m, not resistance per length metrics. The wire won't maintain the same diameter after you solder with it, after all. Resistivity of solder is basically never a concern, though--I think you're looking at the wrong thing here.

Comment: You're not using the solder in as-supplied wire form so your Ohm/m numbers are inapplicable.

Comment: What current was the connector you used rated for? Many cheap barrel jacks are rated for only 4-5 amps, so pushing 200-300% of the max current through them could certainly cause damage.

Comment: The connector is rated for 15A, and the connector is not which is becoming hot. Is the PCB and the cable which is soldered to the PCB. @Hearth, I have never said that I have used the plumbing solder with electronics. I have used it for plumbing and that is why I have it. I have just add it to compare its resistivity. Also I know that I am not using the solder as wire, but maybe is an indicator of its resistivity in the union.

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín The PCB may be damaged or poorly designed; are there any particularly narrow copper traces that carry the current near the connector footprint?

Comment: You included the plumbing solder, which made me think you were considering using it for electronics (not a major mistake unless you use plumbing *flux* too, but you need to add flux and the intentionally-far-from-eutectic alloy will be very difficult to make good joints with)--regardless, the resistance per length metric (where did you even get that? I don't know why that would ever be specified) is just the resistivity divided by cross-sectional area, so you could multiply it out and get the resistivity.

Comment: @Hearth I'll take a look, because I have to disassemble the laptop and now I am just using it (I cannot play games but is usable in low consumption tasks). About how I have got the resistivity, I have shorted the probes to get the cable resistance and I have configured the multimeter in "relative" measurement. Then I have got about 50cm of every solder wire I have, and I have measured the resistance between the ends (multiplying by two).

Comment: Ah, so you just measured it, I thought you meant you had the data from the manufacturer or something.

Comment: Resistivity unit is ohm-meter, not ohms/m. The SI unit, ohm, is lowercase. Mr. Ohm gets a capital.

Comment: @Hearth yep, I'm very desperate with the problem and the next I am trying is to reduce the resistance between the cable and the PCB, that is where the connections is getting very hot. That is why I'm looking into the solders wires to find the lowest resistance possible.

Comment: As I said, the solder resistivity is not the problem; the problem is most likely either a fault in the board, bad solder joints, or a problem with the board design.

Comment: @Hearth yes, they are possible, because I am very dissapointed with the general design of this laptop and is not strange to find a poor board desing too. Also maybe I have damaged the board trying to fix the original connector. For now I'll work in the easier to fix problem, which is the bad solder joints. I'll try to remove all the solder from the board and I'll clean it with alcohol. Then I'll solder a new connector to see if it works or heats as hell like the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned yourself, the solder has a relatively low resistance of a few milliohms. Even if the soldering point were 2mm thick you would have to expect 48mOhms (at 0.24 Ohm / meter), which corresponds to 7 mW at 12 A. Nothing gets warm from it - you can't even see it under the thermal imaging camera.

No, the problem is soldering points that are repeatedly soldered together with different solders. Without completely removing the old material. The resulting alloy is not homogeneous and the solder joint has a lower strength. If these solder joints break, the contact resistance becomes quite high, which later leads to failure. Heating not ruled out, but I haven't had it yet.

Comment: Thanks!. I have removed almost all the old solder tin, but the drill is very small and I was not able to remove it completely. I'll try to do it again doing also a deep clean with alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

Most like it is the oxidation resistance on the barrel pin interfaces.  try Electrical cleaner or isoprop with a toothbrush or Q tip.

Estimate 0.5W resistor of heat and 10A  \$R=P/I^2=0.5/100=50 ~m\Omega\$ for two (2) contact pairs.  That is a normal range for even 10 A relays. So you need a better connector or a cleaner one.  I had the damn same issue on an Asus lappie with 6A charger and it is still dead but  lived a good life.

So clean it and hope for the best.

HNY

*I swore I never would install Win 10 so I tried Win 11. i liked some of it but hated the latency on an i7 16GB so I went back to Win 7 Premium.* mo betta.

Comment: Thanks for the info!. The barrel doesn't seems to be the problem because its temperature is quite low compared with the cable zone that is soldered to the PCB, and that is why I have thought in the solder alloy (the cable is not directly in contact with the PCB, but in the barrel side is in direct contact with the pin). I'll try to clean up the PCB tracks with alcohol to see if works.

Comment: If poss. ,Add solder to tracks or a thin wire, where they get hot, then if that works , coat it.